# How to copy all the rows having same ID from one pandas dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a lot of rows in my pandas dataframe and I want to make a new dataframe containing all the rows for each differnet ID present in my dataframe.

this is the basic layout of the data that i have

| ID | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Three |
| 1 | b | Three |
| 2 | c | Three |
| 1 | d | Three |
| 3 | e | Three |
| 5 | f | Three |

and this is what i am trying to get

| ID | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | Three |
| 1 | b | Three |
| 1 | d | Three |

and so on for each and every ID.
Please help.

Comment: So you want to have a list of dataframes?

Comment: @richardec yeah i want to create a new dataframe for each and every id in the data but because there are more than 2000 different ID's and they are random and not in a sequence i am unable to find a way to do anything.

Comment: `groupby` is the way to go. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use list comprehension with `groupby`:

```
dataframes = [d for _, d in df.groupby('ID')]
```

Output:

```
>>> dataframes
[   ID name  score
 0   1    a  Three
 1   1    b  Three
 3   1    d  Three,
    ID name  score
 2   2    c  Three,
    ID name  score
 4   3    e  Three,
    ID name  score
 5   5    f  Three]
 
 
>>> dataframes[0]
   ID name  score
0   1    a  Three
1   1    b  Three
3   1    d  Three

>>> dataframes[1]
   ID name  score
2   2    c  Three
```

Comment: thank you so much. I should learn groupby by heart. But why is there a _ , does that mean something?

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')` basically returns a list of tuples, where each tuple has two items: the first the is thing unique value for that group, the second is the dataframe iteself. `_` is just a dummy variable name that's often used to indicate the variable is not used.